# ¿Como imprimir elementos repetidos de una std::list en C++ sin usar bucles?

Tags: c++, lista

¿Como hago para imprimir todos los elementos de una lista (std::list) de `pairs` en c++, que contengan `max_elemnt` **repetidos**?

```
list<pair<int, int>> l;
l.push_back ( std::make_pair ( 1, 90 ) );
l.push_back ( std::make_pair ( 2, 90 ) );
l.push_back ( std::make_pair ( 3, 75 ) );
l.push_back ( std::make_pair ( 4, 40 ) );
l.push_back ( std::make_pair ( 5, 90 ) );
```

Es decir... si tengo esa lista de arriba, cómo hago para que la salida sea:

> Alumno 1: 90.
>   Alumno 2: 90.
>   Alumno 5: 90.

...Mostrando no solo el mayor elemento, si no que el mayor elemento y todos los repetidos. No se si me expreso bien.

Tengo entendido que [max_element](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/) tan solo me retorna el primer elemento de la lista. Si tengo una lista con los elementos `{3,7,9,5,6,4,9}`, **y como podemos ver hay dos repetidos**, si hago algo como:

```
int myints[] = {3,7,9,5,6,4,9};
std::cout << *std::max_element(myints,myints+7) << '\n';
```

La salida seria:

> 9

Necesito que la salida sea todos los números repetidos, o sea como hay 2, pues que imprima todos los números mayores repetidos, pero usando el `pair` que vemos en el primer ejemplo.

¿Existe alguna utilidad que muestre todos los repetidos?

Comment: ¿por qué la restricción en el uso de bucles? No hay forma de resolverlo sin usar un bucle. Aunque no lo escribas tu, si existe una rutina que te devuelva lo que buscas, la rutina, internamente, de una forma u otra utilizará bucles.

Comment: No me importa si internamente haga con bucles. El caso es que como existe max_element que retorna el mayor valor **cómodamente**, puede exista algo parecido que retorne todos los valores y no solo uno. Ya sabes... por el del aprovechamiento. =) 

Me parece un absurdo que tengamos que programar algo para imprimir valores repetidos y que sin embargo tengamos una función para obtener el mayor valor. ¿No crees?

Comment: @vangodp No, no es absurdo. La función `max_element()` es sólo para sacar el mayor valor, no importa cuantas veces se repita. Un aproximado de por qué los devs no hicieron esa comodidad que buscas, es que hay algoritmos para uniones, intersecciones que varian en rendimiento, dependiendo de la plataforma.

Prácticamente, estas pidiendo una nueva lista, que haga `push_back` a un par que tenga el mismo valor, cosa que es posible pero _complicado_ cuando hablamos de genéricos en C++...

Comment: @vangodp puedes transformar tu lista en un `heap` con [make_heap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/) y luego sacar los elementos hasta encontrar uno más chico que el primer elemento del `heap`. Entiendo que deberías armar un función de compare para poder comparar sólo una parte del par.
Otra opción, armas un `hash` donde la `clave` son las notas y mientras lo armas, guardas la nota más alta. Luego buscas en el `hash` los valores asociados a la nota más alta.

Comment: @El Asiduo Gracias por la sugerencia man, voy a dar una mirada en lo que sugieres para ver que onda, pero buscaba algo simples, al parecer no hay nada simples para ese caso. >_< ¡Gracias de todos modos!

Comment: @jachguate esas limitaciones *absurdas* son a las que [me refiero](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/588/preguntas-de-hacedme-el-ejercicio-que-me-han-mandado) en preguntas generalmente relacionadas con ejercicios.

Comment: @jachguate Sí hay forma de resolverlo sin usar un bucle. vangodp, muchas gracias por esta excelente pregunta, incluso un programador experimentado en C++ puede aprender algo de ella. Ojalá podamos seguir disfrutando de tus preguntas en StackOverflow en Español.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos, claro que no la hay. Vuelve a leer mi comentario original. Quizás sea simplemente un problema de redacción de la pregunta, pero lo cierto es que, aunque TU no tengas que escribir bucle alguno, las rutinas que invoques internamente tendrán uno o más bucles. La pregunta dice claramente _sin usar bucles_ (independientemente de quien los haya escrito). Eso, en términos prácticos no es posible. He leído tu respuesta, y es ingeniosa, pero como tu mismo acotas, la propia llamada recursiva será, en la mayoría de los casos, resuelta mediante un bucle por el compilador.

Comment: @jachguate es posible resolverlo usando rutinas que no usen bucles. En el peor de los casos tendrías que reescribir parte de esas librerías. Y usando un compilador que no optimice la recursividad por cola en bucles. Es difícil, puede que requiera mucho trabajo y no es práctico. Pero no es imposible hacer lo que pide el autor en C++ sin bucles. De hecho, TODO lo que puede hacer una máquina de Turing puede ser programado sin bucles.

Comment: @Jose, no dudo ni niego que sea teóricamente posible, pero no es práctico, al menos para el programador promedio que no hace sus propios compiladores ni cuenta con el conocimiento, presupuesto y/o tiempo para hacerlo. Re-leyendo mi primer comentario, veo que he caído en afirmar categóricamente algo incorrecto, aunque para efectos prácticos así sea. Te concedo tu parte de razón, y mantengo la postura y acoto, *en términos prácticos* hacer eso no es viable, razonable y, por tanto, posible para el programador promedio, como parece ser el OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma, que si pones en un .h, podría ser "la utilidad" :)

```
inline
void mostrarMayores(std::list<std::pair<int,int>> l)
// recibe una copia para no modificar la lista original
{
    auto comp = [](const std::pair<int,int>& a, const std::pair<int,int>& b) {
        return a.second > b.second;
    };

    auto as_str = [](const std::pair<int, int>& p) {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << "Alumno " << p.first << ": " << p.second;
        return ss.str();
    };

    l.sort(comp);

    std::transform(l.begin(), std::upper_bound(l.begin(), l.end(), *l.begin(), comp),
                   std::ostream_iterator< std::string >( std::cout, "\n" ),
                   as_str);
}
```

Comment: Me parece que sí... esa va ser la única forma, implementarlo yo mismo =(. Gracias man.

Comment: @vangodp Bueno, esta es una forma de implementarlo. No esperabas que el lenguaje tuviera algún algoritmo mágico std::solve_what_i_am_thinking(), ¿verdad?

Comment: Púes lo tiene para muchas cosas. ¿Quieres que te ponga ejemplos?>_<

Answer (score 0):

No conozco ninguna utilidad que haga directamente muestre todos los repetidos.

Pero sí es posible hacerlo sin bucles. Usando recursividad.

Primero obtendremos el máximo con una función `dameMax`.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <list>
#include<stdexcept>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int dameMaxRecursivo( int max, std::list<pair<int, int>>::const_iterator it,
                      std::list<pair<int,int>>::const_iterator end )
{
    if ( it==end )
        return max;
    if ( it->second>max )
        return dameMaxRecursivo( it->second, ++it, end );
    else
        return dameMaxRecursivo( max, ++it, end );
}

int dameMax( const std::list<pair<int, int>>& lista )
{
    if ( lista.size()==0 )
        throw invalid_argument("dameMax requiere una lista no vacia.");
    auto it = lista.begin();
    int max = it->second;
    ++it;
    return dameMaxRecursivo( max, it, lista.end() );
}
```

dameMax comprueba que la lista no esté vacía y llama a la función recursiva pasando el máximo hasta ahora (el valor del primer elemento de la lista) y un iterador al siguiente elemento. También pasa iterador al final para que la función recursiva sepa cuando parar.

Primero la función recursiva comprueba si ha llegado al final. Si no compara el máximo hasta ahora con el elemento en el iterador recibido. Si es mayor se llama a si misma con este nuevo valor que es mayor y con el iterador apuntando al siguiente elemento, si no es mayor se llama a si misma con el máximo hasta ahora y también con el iterador apuntando al siguiente elemento.

Para imprimirlos sin bucles usamos la misma técnica:

```
void mostarMayoresRecursivo( int max, std::list<pair<int, 
                             int>>::const_iterator it,
                             std::list<pair<int,int>>::const_iterator end)
{
    if ( it==end ) 
        return;
    if ( it->second == max )
      std::cout<<"Alumno " << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;
    mostarMayoresRecursivo( max, ++it, end );
}

void mostrarMayores( const std::list<pair<int, int>>& lista )
{
    if ( lista.size()==0 )
        return;
    int max = dameMax( lista );
    mostarMayoresRecursivo( max, lista.begin(), lista.end() );
}
```

Un lector avezado podrá observar que todavía hay bucles. Es muy posible que el operador << para streams esté implementado con algún bucle. Por supuesto esto también es posible implementarlo sin bucles usando la misma técnica.
La recursión utilizada, que es recursión de cola, puede ser optimizada por algunos compiladores a un bucle. Pero también es posible obligar al compilador a no hacerlo.
Y es posible que las llamadas a sistema para imprimir en pantalla usen un mecanismo de buffer y acaben imprimiendo en un bucle pese a que les pases los caracteres de uno en uno sin bucles. Pero esto ya es algo externo a tu programa.

Que se pueda hacer así no significa que sea recomendable. Hay casos en que sí es recomendable, es una técnica habitual en programación funcional.